# 100% Div with repeating background image media query

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm having trouble nailing down a solution to this.

I have a div with a repeating background image that's 100% across the screen. So lets say:

```
.services_wrap {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background:url('../images/services_tile.png') repeat-x;
}

<div class="services_wrap">
    //Content
</div>
```

How do I specify a media query that will scale that entire div down when the screen is resized, like for a normal div it would be:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {

    /*Makes the logo shrink*/
    #header {
            height:auto;
    }
}
```

But If I try this with .services_wrap nothing happens.

I have tried background-size: properties with no luck.

Is it possible to scale a repeating image?

Comment: Hope this resolves your query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812890/vertical-repeating-resizable-border-images-using-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `background-size`

```
div {
    background: url("//www.placehold.it/50x50") repeat-x;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    div {
        background-size: 25px;
    }
}
```

​
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dwSLu/)

Comment: Here is another [example](http://jsfiddle.net/dwSLu/1/) of scaling other elements with the backgrounds using `em`s.

Comment: This worked partially for me, but instead I decided to just remove the background the image and make it a solid color at a certain size. Thank you for you input.